# How do you translate "Top 10 X" (in the title of an article or video)?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

A popular kind of article and videos are *Top 10 X*, which is a list of 10 X things that are considered the best by the author. In French, we often add a grammatical article to this expression: *Top 10 des X*.

I am having trouble translating this expression. The best I can think of is *La 10 plejaj X*

Answer (score 2):

Apud la jam proponitaj "la dek plej ..." eblas ankaŭ uzi "La pintaj 10". "La 10 plejaj" laŭ mi estas erara formo.

Answer (score 1):

*furordeko* seems to be a word that is out there.

Furoro is a smash hit, bestseller, etc. And dek is ten.

Furoro is also combined, for example, with with *song* to mean something like top song, or hit song: furorkanto.

So, in your example, I think you could say, "La Furordeko X".

- http://www.simplavortaro.org/vorto/furoro
- https://www.google.com/search?q=furordeko

Comment: I like this suggestion. However the results from the Google search smell suspiciously of automatic translation. On the other hand the robot translators must have learnt it from somewhere too so it must exist.

Comment: That seems suited only if the list is about popularity. If I make a Top 10 of the most dangerous animals, I don't think "Furordeko" will suit.

Comment: Kial ne... La plej bonaj 10 kantoj, aŭ la plej danĝeraj 10 bestoj, ktp? Mem hispane ne ekzistas traduko por TOP kaj oni uzas TOP 10 ankaŭ.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply say "*la 10 plej bonaj/popularaj/interesaj/ktp X*". This makes it clear what you are talking about, that is, in what way the things in the list are "top", and in Esperanto clearer is generally better.

"*La 10 Plejaj X*", at least for me, makes me think "*plej kiaj?*", and the most literal translation "*La 10 Supraj X*" may be usable in some contexts, but could be confusing depending on the reader's background.